# How can I include a local header file in Rcpp inline, without hardcoding the directory?

Tags: r, rcpp

I have an R script with some inline C++, and I'd like to include a header file in the same directory.  I can get the following to work:

```
library(Rcpp)
library(inline)

code <- '
   // my C++ code here
   '

settings=getPlugin("Rcpp")
settings$env$PKG_CXXFLAGS='-I /hard/coded/path/to/header/'

myfunction <- cxxfunction(signature(x="numeric"),
                          plugin="Rcpp",  include='#include "myheader.hpp"',
                          settings=settings, body=code)
```

But it seems like there should be a convenient way to include a header file in the same directory.  I just can't see what it is.  I'd really like a way to include c++ files which are located in the same directory.

(Also apologies: I'm not a c++ (or R) ninja, so I may be missing something very obvious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you clarify what directory you refer to when you say "in the same directory"? Same as what?

If it is the current directory, you still need `-I.` as that directory may not added as a default.  But if that is indeed the directory you want, then its *relative* path (saying "current dir") is more general than the absolute `-I/hard/coded/path/to/header`.

Otherwise, what you have done is the correct way to modify the plugin to provide extra flags to the compiler.

**Edit:** Made a test or two and it turns out that the [inline](http://cran.r-project.org/package=inline) package always use R's tempdir to compile -- so `-I.` makes no sense as we generally do not know where that is.

That leaves you with two choices:

1. Use an absolute path as you have done.
2. Use R to read the content of the header file into a variable passed to the `include=` argument.

**Edit 2:**  Turns out that we do that in one of the examples shipped with Rcpp itself:

```
settings <- getPlugin("Rcpp")
settings$env$PKG_CXXFLAGS <- paste("-I", getwd(), sep="")
```

and then uses   settings=settings   in the call to cxxfunction.

Comment: The same directory = the directory in which the R script and CPP files are located.  I just noticed that in the "sugarbenchmarks.r" example script, the current working directory is obtained with getwd(), and this is used with the -I flag as above.  Is that the canonical way of solving this problem?

Comment: Using `-I.` is the easiest way to add the current directory. I think you could also do it for all your R projects via `CXXFLAGS` in `~/.R/Makevars`

Comment: Pleasure. Hope to see your over at the rcpp-devel list which tends to regroup more Rcpp folks than here.